# how to filter text inside HTML tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to grab text inside a div element like this :

```
<div class='someclass'> 
<blockquote>some text ! </blockquote>
another text goes here . 
</div>
```

so I get all text with jQuery like this:

```
var qtext = $('.someclass').text();
```

I want to exclude text that's in child elements, e.g.  `<blockquote>some text ! </blockquote>`. I just need the text inside div element. How can I filter that ?

Comment: i don't need to strip HTML tags i need to remove entire HTML tag with text inside of it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a workaround :

```
var div = $('.someclass').clone();
div = div.find('blockquote').remove().end();
alert(div.text());
```

Answer (score 1):

See "strip HTML tags": http://devkick.com/blog/parsing-strings-with-jquery/

Comment: Yeah , that's perfect but it's only clear html tags . i need to clear html tag with the text inside of it .

Answer (score 0):

What you want is only to select the TextNodes:

```
var textNodes =   $('.someclass').contents()
                                 .filter(function() {
                                   return this.nodeType ==  Node.TEXT_NODE;
                                 });
```

That will give you an array of TextNodes, you could then  extract the actual text content of all the nodes to an array:

```
var textContents = $.map(textNodes, function(n){return n.textContent;});
```